# Using aws-sdk to download files from s3. Encoding not right

Tags: ruby, pdf, encoding, amazon-s3

I am trying to use aws-sdk to load s3 files to local disk, and question why my pdf file (which just has a text saying SAMPLE PDF) turns out with an apparently empty content.

I guess it has something to do with the encoding...but how can i fix it?

Here is my code :

```
require 'aws-sdk'

bucket_name = "****"
access_key_id = "***"
secret_access_key = "**"

s3=AWS::S3.new(
access_key_id: access_key_id,
secret_access_key: secret_access_key)

b = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
filen = File.basename("Sample.pdf")

path = "original/90/#{filen}"
o = b.objects[path]

require 'tempfile'

ext= File.extname(filen)

file = File.open("test.pdf","w", encoding: "ascii-8bit")
# streaming download from S3 to a file on disk

begin
file.write(o.read) do |chunk|
    file.write(chunk)
end
end
file.close
```

If i take out the `encoding: "ascii-8bit"`, i just get an error message `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

Comment: When you open the file, try using "wb" (write + binary) instead of only "w".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and a tip from a cousin of mine, i finally got this to work.

Instead of using the aws solution to load the file from amazon and write it to disk (which was generating a strange pdf file : apparently equal to the original, but with blank content, and Adobe Reader "fixing" it when opening)
i instead am now using open-uri, with SSL ignore.

Here is the final code which made my day :

```
require 'open-uri'
open('test.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('https://s3.amazon.com/mybucket/Sample.pdf',:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE).read
end
```

Comment: It's the 'b' flag I was missing when opening the file! Thank you so much!